# split sentence on words using JS without 'split' function

Tags: javascript

I need to split sentence on words using JavaScript without 'split' function and return every word using alert function. So, I have this code, but it doesn't work. I am a newbie in programming, help me with this question.

```
var str = 'Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum';
var new_str = ' ';
for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    if(str == new_str) {
        alert( new_str );
        new_str = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `str.split(",")`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I need to do it without using 'split' function

Comment: Any specific reason?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale you know, I need to do it without any function. just add new variable

Comment: The idea is you need to read character one-by-one. if it isn't a space. you append that character to `new_str`. if it is a space, you append `new_str` to an array and reset `new_str` to an empty string. and continue until the end for the original string.

Comment: @digitake yes, but what`s problem in my code. I can`t understand

Comment: Try my variant, @juicy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var str = 'Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum';
var new_str = '';
for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    if(str[i] == ' ') {     // Problem 1) you need to check against space
        alert( new_str );   
        new_str = '';
    } else  {               // Problem 2) you need to append character to new_str
        new_str += str[i];
    }
}
alert( new_str );    // Problem 3) you need the last alert for end of string
```

Comment: @Juicy Enjoy learning ;). Please click accept the answer if the answer helps you.

Comment: I have one question. Why do you wrote new_str += str[i]? I thought I need to write str[i] += new_str. Can you explain me?

Comment: Minus for `==`, `var` and snake_cased names. Oh also for `else` instead of `continue`. Check my `reduce` below.

Comment: because `new_str` in this case is a `buffer` to keep track of a string we saw so far.
if you write `str[i] += new_str`. the result will be
`str[i] += ''`  which will be the same as `new_str` is empty.

on the other hand,
`new_str += str[i]` means

new_str = '' + 'L'   // For i = 0
new_str = 'L' + 'o'   // For i = 1
new_str = 'Lo' + 'r'   // For i = 2
new_str = 'Lor' + 'e'   // For i = 3

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Piterden I tried to change original code as less possible as it will be easier for the learner. Also `else` is better practise than `continue` from the syntax perspective as sematically in this case interpreter will generate exactly the same instructions.

Comment: @Piterden you can start the new thread on that as a compiler related issue. I have no comment on a subjective comment.

Comment: @Piterden what is funny is 1) you don't dare to open the new thread to welcome opinion from guys who truly know and design a compiler? 2) you simply mix up `semantic` with `performance`. It is not the same thing. 3) try to swap to code chunk of block 1 and block 2. I got if-else 5% faster what does that mean? i can capture for you if you wanna see the image. but i think i'm wasting time here. good luck with a new thread on this.

Comment: @Piterden actually i captured it. Just hope you don't think i play any trick with it. i simply click refresh this time. so reliable result eh? https://imgur.com/a/xagi9ZU

Comment: So are instructions the same? Man, maybe you should learn self, before helpig other people with your bulshity knowledge

Comment: @Piterden i thought you would question that so here it is: https://imgur.com/a/WOXNeLP

Comment: @Piterden you don't know me. so you can't judge me. but yeah. I designed compiler and I can guess that you don't. and yes. after the optimization phase, the result instructions are the same.

Comment: I don't need to know you. Your code is enough for me to evaluate your skills and neatness. What compiler did you designed? If you even don't know that `==` is not correct for JS...

Comment: @Piterden 1) you can check my article in the profile :). Basically, I design in-house compiler for language extension lke ppx. I mainly use LALR/Earley. Also, I design syntax extension e.g. Monad for option type . 2) same I don't need to know you that you aren't the person who read carefully. As I have pointed out that I preserved the original code as much as possible for the sake of learning. 3) `==` is not wrong it's just semantic different. 4) you just started writing JS huh? do you understand the word `semantic`?

Comment: I had designed the native typization for JS https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Piterden/vanilla-typization Also I see the nice semantic inside your four repositories https://github.com/digitake?utf8=%E2%9C%93&tab=repositories&q=&type=source&language= You can compare with my stuff https://github.com/Piterden?utf8=%E2%9C%93&tab=repositories&q=&type=source&language= Btw, my linter don't allow me to write `==` for compare.

Comment: @Piterden okay. I will check when free. and no that's not a meaning of programming semantics if you implies that.

Comment: Do you understand word `consistency`? Probably you should read this article https://github.com/rwaldron/idiomatic.js/

Comment: @Piterden how is that relevant here? I can keep the things back to place.
1) you say snake_case and `==` is wrong. I say no it's not. it's for newcomer to capture the basica understanding. 2) I say if-else/continue in for-loop are semantically the same. your counter argument is `performance` 3) I show back it's indifferent you just refresh. you neglect. 4) I asked back do you understand the meaning of `semantics`. you neglect` 5) you asked which compiler i designed i answered. 6) now what in the world `consistency` come in here? Ok. Sry You win. you are the smartest guy... kid

Comment: @Piterden friendly suggestion. your vanilla-typization based on preserved-order assumption, which JavaScript doesn't guarantee object property order(ECMA-262 12.6.4) so it can break upon different implementation.

Comment: @Piterden okay. i'm done with this. happy coding. :)

Answer (score 2):

A more concise version:

```js
var str = 'Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum';

var word = '', result = []

for (const char of str) {
  word = char == ' ' ? (result.push(word), "") : (word + char);
}

result.push(word);

console.log(result)
```

We are using `for` short version and mainly the ternary operator to deal with the logic when to push a word ready for the result array and when to keep concatenating.

Another version without the last `result.push(word)` would look like this:

```js
var str = 'Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum';
var word = '', result = []

for(const i in str) {
   word = str[i]==' ' || (+i==str.length-1) ? (result.push((word+str[i]).trimEnd()), '') : (word+str[i])
}

console.log(result)
```

Notice the difference from `for(const char **of** str)` vs `for(const i **in** str)` ... one gives you the actual character when the other the actual index.

Comment: Doesn't handle last item

Comment: @akrion Have you noticed that the code ignores the last string?

Comment: So close to beautiful

Comment: I fixed the last string thing and beautified it a bit, feel free to roll back :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

```
var str = 'Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum';
var new_str = '';
for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    if(str[i] == ' ') {
        alert( new_str );
        new_str = '';
    } else {
        new_str += str[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Juicy Updated the answer. Try now

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum';
var new_str = ' ';
var word = '';
for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    if(str[i] == new_str) {
        alert( word );
        word = '';
    }
    else {
      word += str[i]
    }
}
alert(word)
```

if `str[i]` is not space string add it to `word`, else alert it and clear `word`

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum";
var item = '';
var last_item = 0;
for(var i=0;i<str.length;++i){
    if(str[i]==" "){
        item = str.slice(last_item,i);
        if(i+1<str.length){
            last_item = i+1;
        }
        alert(item);
    }
}
item = str.slice(last_item,str.length);
alert(item);
```

This snippet is tested and working well ;)
Good luck with your learning

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function like this, also you can replace console.log with alert :

let string ="how are you";

```
let getWordsFromString = (string) =>
{
    let word = "";

    for(let i=0;i<string.length;++i)
    {
        if(string.charAt(i) === ' ')
        {
            console.log(word);
            word = "";
            while(i<string.length-1 && string.charAt(i+1) === ' ') ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            word += string.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    if(word.length>0)
        console.log(word);
}

getWordsFromString(string);
```

Comment: a bit over-complicated wouldn't you say?

Answer (score -2):

```js
const str = 'Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum';

// The first way is RegEx
const array = str.match(/\w+/g);
array.forEach(alert);

// The second way is reduce
let index = 0;
const result = Array.from(str)
  .reduce((acc, char) => {
    acc[index] = acc[index] || [];
    if (char !== ' ') {
      acc[index].push(char);
      return acc;
    }
    index++;
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .map((wordArray) => wordArray.join(''));

result.forEach(alert);
```

Comment: @Juicy, Updated. Added the alternative way

Comment: minus for 1) overly complicated 2) not answer the question as the question asked for avoiding `split` and using alert function.

Comment: Why not answer? I had avoid split. Where do you see split in my code? Which way do you mean talking complicated?

Comment: the question joint with `and` operator if one is false. the whole is false. basic logic. yeah?

Comment: Updated as your Majesty wish